# Friend function how can i change their members globally

Tags: c++, class, global-variables, friend-function

how can i change the members of a friend function globally, not just inside its block? i have a simple example below:

Expected Output(int):
45
35
35

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class dog
{
    private:
        int HealthPoints;
        int Damage;
    public:
    dog(int HealthPoints, int Damage){
        this->HealthPoints = HealthPoints;
        this->Damage = Damage;
    }
    friend void doAttack(dog,dog);
    int getHealthPoints(){return HealthPoints;}
    int getDamage(){return Damage;}
};

void doAttack(dog Attacker, dog Attacked){
    Attacked.HealthPoints = Attacked.HealthPoints - Attacker.Damage;
    cout << Attacked.HealthPoints << "\tvalue inside friend function" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    dog a(45, 10);
    dog b(45, 10);
    cout << b.getHealthPoints() << "\tvalue before friend function" << endl;
    doAttack(a, b);
    cout << b.getHealthPoints() << "\tvalue after friend function";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take your arguments by reference, or else you'll have a copy inside of your function. You should be implementing setter member functions instead of using friend functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want global variables. What you're currently doing is passing `Attacker` and `Attacked` by value - e.g. copying them. You make changes in `doAttack` to these copies. The originals are never modified. Pass them by reference instead.

I have changed the name of your function to be more friendly as well. Feel free to change it back.

```
void doPet(dog& Petter, dog& Petted) {
    Petted.LovePoints = Petted.LovePoints + Petter.Friendliness;
    cout << Petted.LovePoints << "\tvalue inside friend function" << endl;
}
```